# C# - Timer ticks shorter than specified in the interval causing duplicate jobs to run in parallel

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, system.timers.timer

I have a windows service that ticks over every 4 minutes. When the timer ticks if runs a DataImporter, the DataImporter has a number of "Jobs" that it can run on each tick, for example, there is a ProcessData job and a RetreiveData job:

- RetreiveData job will reach out to 3rd party API and store data in DB for processing.
- ProcessData job will take data from DB and process it into our usable DB etc.

As soon as the DataImporter is run it checks a DB table called ScheduledJob - this has a number of scheduling functionality such as FrequencyInterval, ActiveStart/Stop times, StartedLastRun time. The ScheduledJob table has  flag called "InProgress", this flag will stop the DataImport picking up that job when it's already running.

There is a continuous issue where a job is picked up twice, a few seconds apart from each other and then both run simultaneously which cause a number of DB constraints when trying to insert identical records. I am not really sure how it can pick two jobs up at the same time, the tick is 4 minutes apart, so in theory it shouldn't be able to even look at the potential jobs to run, how can it run them both a few seconds apart?

Both the RetrieveData and ProcessData jobs need to be able to run in parallel so I can't pause the Timer whilst I execute the job.

Service:

```
public partial class DataImport : ServiceBase
{
    private int _eventId = 0;
    readonly Timer _serviceTimer = new Timer(240000);

    public DataImport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImportServiceEventLog.Source = ServiceSource.DATA_IMPORT_SERVICE.ToString() + Global.ReleaseModeSource(); ;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ImportServiceEventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceSource.DATA_IMPORT_SERVICE.ToString() + Global.ReleaseModeSource() + " started", EventLogEntryType.Information, _eventId++);
        _serviceTimer.AutoReset = true;
        ImportServiceEventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceSource.DATA_IMPORT_SERVICE.ToString() + Global.ReleaseModeSource() + " timer interval = " + _serviceTimer.Interval / 1000 + " seconds", EventLogEntryType.Information, _eventId++);
        _serviceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);
        _serviceTimer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        ImportServiceEventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceSource.DATA_IMPORT_SERVICE.ToString() + Global.ReleaseModeSource() + " stopped", EventLogEntryType.Information, _eventId++);
    }

    public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            Run();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            ImportServiceEventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceSource.DATA_IMPORT_SERVICE.ToString() + Global.ReleaseModeSource() + " error: " + ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Information, _eventId++);
        }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        using (var dataImportController = new DataImportController())
        {
            dataImportController.Run();
        }                
    }
}
```

DataImportController:

```
public class DataImportController
{
    public void Run()
    {
        // Gets all the jobs from the ScheduledJob table in the DB
        var jobs = GetJobsToRun();

        //Get all Processes (from DB)
        foreach (var job in jobs)
        {
            //Check the time it was last run - do this for each process
            if (RunJob(job))
            {
                _messaging.EventMessage("Process " + job.Name + " finished : " + DateTime.Now, ServiceSource.DATA_IMPORT_SERVICE);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool RunJob(ScheduledJob job)
    {
        // Checks if the job is ready to run, i.e. is the InProgress flag set to false and the interval long enough since the StartedLastRun DateTime
        if (!job.IsReadyToRun())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Set job to in progress
        job.InProgress = true;
        job.StartedLastRun = DateTime.Now;
        _scheduledJobRepository.Update(job);
        _scheduledJobRepository.SaveChanges();

        try
        {
            switch (job.Name.ToUpper())
            {
                case "RetreiveData":
                    // RUN JOB
                    break;
                case "ProcessData":
                    // RUN JOB
                    break;                    
            }

            job.InProgress = false;
            job.EndedLastRun = DateTime.Now;
            _scheduledJobRepository.Update(job);
            _scheduledJobRepository.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _messaging.ReportError("Error occured whilst checking we are ready to run " + exception.Message, exception, null, 0, ServiceSource.DATA_IMPORT_SERVICE);
        }

        return true;
    }   
}
```

EDIT:

Include Program.cs

```
static void Main()
{
    if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
        new DataImport()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you service is stopped, and then started again? If `OnStart` is called twice, it will add another handler to the timer, so every time it ticks `OnTimer` will be called twice in quick succession. However, it should wait until one `OnTimer` invocation has finished before calling it again.

Comment: No there's nothing in the logs to say it was stopped and started.

Comment: Is it possible that you end up with two instances of `DataImport`? E.g. it's specified twice in `ServiceBase.Run`?

Comment: No don't think that's happening, I've included the Program.cs file to show you how it's being called.

Comment: What makes you think the job is picked up twice, a couple of seconds apart? Is that from logging, or are you inferring it from something else? Is it possible that `GetJobsToRun` is returning the same job twice?

Comment: I'm getting it from the EventViewer and can see it being picked up twice, once at 18/10/2019 05:16:59 and the next at 18/10/2019 05:17:06. I've also checked that the GetJobsToRun doesn't return duplicates.

Comment: There's no restart in the EventViewer logs

Answer (score 1):

If overlapping is a concern, ditch the timer and make an async loop, leveraging `Task.Delay`:

```
async Task SomeFunc(CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        DoWork();
        await Task.Delay(timeInterval, token);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this, will have to wait and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this have an issue that it pauses the execution whilst calling DoWork()?

Comment: @cullimorer Indeed. You could mitigate for this by subtracting the time taken to perform the work from the next interval. If it's less than 0, then go again immediately.

Answer (score 0):

try to stop the timer inside the OnTimer function then re-start timer after it has finished executing your task.

Comment: "*Both the RetrieveData and ProcessData jobs need to be able to run in parallel so I can't pause the Timer whilst I execute the job.*"

Answer (score 0):

You subsribe to timer event in `OnStart`, and didn't unsubscribe in `OnStop`.

Move `_serviceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);` and initialization of AutoReset to constructor. Stop timer in `OnStop`. That should fix your issue. I believe your service is started (restarted) more than once.

Comment: This was discussed in the comments, and OP said that their service was not started twice

Comment: That may happen unnoticed, depending on how he reinstall / debug a service. I propose to reboot a PC after compilation and installation of the new version with proposed changes.

Comment: They've already checked, using the logging they have in place, and this is not the cause